# apply a function to factors of each column for all columns of a data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame with 6 columns. The 4 first columns contain 2 factors each.
I would like to write a function (or a for loop) to perform a test (e.g `wilcox.test`) between the factors of each column for values of `pc1` and `pc2` columns.

If i was to do it manually :

```
wilcox.test(df[df$g1=="bm",5],df[df$g1!="bm",5])
wilcox.test(df[df$g1=="bm",6],df[df$g1!="bm",6])
```

How can i get the `p.values` for each test stored in a data frame with `rows` equal to first 4 columns of `df` and `columns` equal `pc1` and `pc2`.

I tried this but it is not correct:

```
mutate_if(df[,head(colnames(df),-2)], is.character, as.factor) %>% #check whether 4 first columns are as factor
  lapply(.,
  function(x) {
    df = data.frame(row.names = head(colnames(df),-2))
         names(df) = c("pc1", "pc2")
         df$pc1 = wilcox.test(df[df$g1=="bm",5],df[df$g1!="bm",5])
         df$pc2 = wilcox.test(df[df$g1=="bm",6],df[df$g1!="bm",6])
         return(df)
       }
)
```

my data frame

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(g1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("bm", "cm"), class = "factor"), g2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("ct", "ft"), class = "factor"), 
    g3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("bn", 
    "un"), class = "factor"), g4 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("ls", "vp"), class = "factor"), 
    pc1 = c(0.86, 0.54, 0.06, 0.88, 0.62, 0.14, 0.94, 0.8, 0.34, 
    0.04), pc2 = c(0.04, 0.9, 0.68, 0.54, 0.92, 0.36, 0.3, 0.62, 
    0.84, 0.96)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below may give you some idea for how to tackle this:

(I didn't generalise it to all tests, as I'm not sure whether all of them would have `p.value` stored in the same location.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

lapply(which(sapply(df, is.factor)),
       function(i) df[, c(i, 5, 6)] %>%

         # set column names & extract group values into a separate label
         # so that the subsequent code can be used for all four columns
         # (the label's wording can be changed as desired)
         setNames(c("group", "pc1", "pc2")) %>%
         filter(!is.na(group)) %>% # filter out NA rows
         mutate(label = paste0("Column ", i, ": ",
                               paste0(unique(as.character(group)),
                                      collapse = " vs "))) %>%
         mutate(group = paste0("group", as.integer(group))) %>%

         # pivot data such that each group of pc1 / pc2 values is in its own column
         group_by(group) %>% 
         mutate(id = seq(1, n())) %>% 
         pivot_wider(id_cols = c(label, id), 
                     names_from = group, 
                     values_from = c(pc1, pc2)) %>%

         # perform separate tests on pc1 & pc2, and extract p-value in each case
         summarise(label = unique(label),
                   pc1 = wilcox.test(pc1_group1, pc1_group2)$p.value,
                   pc2 = wilcox.test(pc2_group1, pc2_group2)$p.value)) %>%

  # combine results from each group
  data.table::rbindlist()

# result:
                label       pc1       pc2
1: Column 1: bm vs cm 1.0000000 1.0000000
2: Column 2: ct vs ft 0.6904762 0.8412698
3: Column 3: un vs bn 0.8412698 1.0000000
4: Column 4: vp vs ls 0.6904762 0.5476190
```

Comment: Thank you for the help @Z.Lin. In my real data frame I have so many columns and I would like to define which columns to be included for the test. however, when I try `lapply(which(sapply(df[,c(10,15,20,22,65,55,40)], is.factor))` I get an error. Can I fix that ? Also is it possible to add a line to indicate when there is NAs with factor columns ignore the NAs, so there are always 2 factors ?

Comment: The `which(sapply(df, is.factor))` line is designed to return the column indices that correspond to the columns you want to use as group variables (assuming they--and only the--are factors). If you prefer to specify them directly, you can simply replace that part with `c(10,15,20,22,65,55,40)`.

Comment: To clarify: If there are NA values in a factor column, you want the corresponding rows of PC1/PC2 dropped from comparison?

Comment: Yes, corresponding rows of PC1/PC2 can be dropped.

Comment: @symo Have edited my answer to filter out NA rows during data processing. Do note that if the number of dropped rows for the first vs. second factor values are not the same, there would be NAs in PC1 / PC2 being passed into the test function. For `wilcox.test`, these would be filtered out automatically (I checked the underlying `stats:::wilcox.test.default` code), but I'm not sure for other possible tests.